# Create scheduled query with bq mk command-line tool from a SQL file

Tags: bash, google-bigquery

I am trying to create a scheduled query using the `bq` command-line tool storing the query to be executed on a sql file named `scheduled_query.sql`, but I am not able to have it working. I am checking [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_mk) documentation.

I want to schedule the following query:

```
INSERT INTO github_actions_test_dataset.timestamp_to_unix
SELECT
    CURRENT_DATETIME("Europe/Madrid") AS timestamp, 
    UNIX_MILLIS(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) AS unix_miliseconds
```

For this, I have executed the following command with success:

```
bq mk --transfer_config --display_name='Example Scheduled Query' --target_dataset=github_actions_test_dataset --service_account_name=my-sa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com --data_source=scheduled_query --params='{"query":"INSERT INTO github_actions_test_dataset.timestamp_to_unix SELECT CURRENT_DATETIME(\"Europe/Madrid\") AS timestamp, UNIX_MILLIS(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) AS unix_miliseconds"}'
```

However, instead of having to write the query in the command I want to retrieve it from a `.sql` file, and feed it to the command. I tried using `sed 's/"/\\"/g' scheduled_query.sql` in order to escape de `"` character in my query like this:

```
bq mk --transfer_config --display_name='Example Scheduled Query' --target_dataset=$DATASET --service_account_name=github-actions-sa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com --data_source=scheduled_query --params='{"query":"'$(sed 's/"/\\"/g' scheduled_query.sql)'"}'
```

But again received

```
Too many positional args, still have ['SELECT', 'CURRENT_DATETIME(\\"Europe/Madrid\\")', 'AS', 'timestamp,', 'UNIX_MILLIS(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())', 'AS', 'unix_miliseconds"}']
```

The solution may be more related on how to concatenate quoted strings on a bash command. What am I doing wrong? Note that I want to use the `bq mk` command, not the `bk query` one.

Comment: Can you try putting the contents of scheduled_query.sql as INSERT INTO github_actions_test_dataset.timestamp_to_unix SELECT CURRENT_DATETIME("Europe/Madrid") AS timestamp, UNIX_MILLIS(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) AS unix_miliseconds
and using bq mk --transfer_config --display_name='Example Scheduled Query' --target_dataset=$DATASET --service_account_name=github-actions-sa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com --data_source=scheduled_query --params='{"query":"scheduled_query.sql"}'

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that would take the filename as a literal since it is inside single quotes @PriyaAgarwal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to use the `bq mk` command after applying a couple transformations to the content of the file:

```
QUERY=$(tr -s '[:space:]' ' ' < scheduled_query.sql | sed 's/"/\\"/g')
PARAMS='{"query":"'$QUERY'"}'
bq mk --transfer_config --display_name="Example scheduled query" --location=EU --data_source=scheduled_query --schedule='every day 06:45' --params="$PARAMS"
```

I will explain them:

- `tr -s '[:space:]' ' ' < scheduled_query.sql` : as the query needed to be inserted on a json-like object, the new line characters and tabs where causing a `Too many positional args` error. To solve it, I substituted any consecutive number of spacing characters with a blank. Most probably there is a better alternative that keeps the original format, but after several days of trying things this worked for me.
- `sed 's/"/\\"/g'` : also, as we are providing the query inside a json we need to scape all the double quotes inside my query so that they don't mess up with the field delimiter ones.

With this I was able to load any query I have tried without problems. The only limitation I have found has been when the query contains a line comment. As we are getting rid of the new line characters, if a line comment appears on the query it will comment out all the lines which were after it, so you will have to manually remove them or apply any other rule that automatically finds and delete them.

**BONUS:**

I used this piece of code to create a scheduled query from `Github Actions`. If you came here for the same reason, you can have a look to the logic I implemented to see if it fits your use case:

```
QUERY_DISPLAYNAME="Example scheduled query"
QUERY=$(tr -s '[:space:]' ' ' < $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/queries/scheduled_query.sql | sed 's/"/\\"/g')
PARAMS='{"query":"'$QUERY'"}'
RESULT=$(bq ls --format=json --transfer_config --transfer_location=eu | jq -r '.[] | select(.displayName=="'"$QUERY_DISPLAYNAME"'")')
if ! [[ "$RESULT" ]];
then
    bq mk --transfer_config --display_name="$QUERY_DISPLAYNAME" --location=EU --service_account_name=${{ secrets.SA_NAME }} --data_source=scheduled_query --schedule='every day 06:45' --params="$PARAMS"
else
    QUERY_NAME=$(echo $RESULT | jq -r '.name')  
    bq update --transfer_config --params="$PARAMS" $QUERY_NAME
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following approach:

```
QUERY="$(cat test_sql.sql)"

bq query \
--append_table=true \
--destination_table=elZagales:so_test.timestamp_to_unix \
--display_name='test run' \
--schedule='every 15 minutes' \
--use_legacy_sql=false \
$QUERY
```

Utilizing this approach you simply just pass it as a query that has been set as a shell variable.

This results in the creation of a scheduled query here:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please elaborate what the `bq mk` alternative would be? I also need to use `bq update` so I want to use the mk command as they have the same syntax